# Как вставить функцию с break в цикл while?

Tags: python

```
def enter_x():
    x = input("*: ")
    if x == 'quit':
        break


while True:

    print("> Вы проснулись в подземелье ")
    print("> К вам идёт злобный троль")

    v1 = int(
        input("\t•1 Я его ударю!\n\t•2 Кто ты?\n\t•3 Мне нужно бежать!\n"))
    if v1 == 1:
        health -= 5
        print("> Это была плохая идея. Троль отразил вашу атаку. Вы вмазали себе в морду...")
```

Как вставить рабочую функцию в цикл?
Ожидается что при вводе quit, цикл останавливается.

Answer (score 4):

самое простое - вы принимаете текстовую команду, обрабатываете ее и лишь потом переводите в числа и т.д.

```
while True:

    print("> Вы проснулись в подземелье ")
    print("> К вам идёт злобный троль")
    
    command = input("\t•1 Я его ударю!\n\t•2 Кто ты?\n\t•3 Мне нужно бежать!\n")

    if command == 'quit':
        break

    v1 = int(command)

    if v1 == 1:
        health -= 5
        print("> Это была плохая идея. Троль отразил вашу атаку. Вы вмазали себе в морду...")
```

P.S.

и "троль" пишется все таки с двумя л - **тролль**, если конечно вы не на украинском пишите :)

Answer (score 3):

```
def inp(msg, data_type = str):
    x = input(msg)
    return inp.quit if (x == inp.quit) else data_type(x)

inp.quit = 'quit'
# сохранена в виде свойства, чтобы по коду не разбрасывать строки,
# значение 'quit' можно будет легко изменить.

###

while True:
    print("> Вы проснулись в подземелье ")
    print("> К вам идёт злобный троль")

    v1 = inp("\t•1 Я его ударю!\n\t•2 Кто ты?\n\t•3 Мне нужно бежать!\n", int)
    if v1 == inp.quit: # <-- функция вернула значение inp.quit, значит ввели 'quit'
        break
    elif v1 == 1:
        health -= 5
        print("> Это была плохая идея. Троль отразил вашу атаку. Вы вмазали себе в морду...")
```

Answer (score 1):

можно так, используя `iter`

```
def enter_x():
    return input("*: ")

for _ in iter(enter_x, "quit"):

    print("> Вы проснулись в подземелье ")
    print("> К вам идёт злобный троль")

    v1 = int(
        input("\t•1 Я его ударю!\n\t•2 Кто ты?\n\t•3 Мне нужно бежать!\n"))
    if v1 == 1:
        health -= 5
        print("> Это была плохая идея. Троль отразил вашу атаку. Вы вмазали себе в морду...")
```